# XMLA operation failed. You are either using an older version of Analysis Services client libraries or SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have an AMO project that I'm using to automate operations against a ssas tabular 2016 model.

Moving the model into azure analysis services tabular, I get the below error when the library runs:

> XMLA operation failed. You are either using an older version of Analysis Services client libraries or SQL Server Management Studio. Please upgrade to the latest version. More information can be found here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=860248

I've tried downloading the latest version of the library from the link, however that only has a

- Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DLL

  in

  > C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices\v4.0_14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

Whereas my solution previously used two dlls:

- Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.dll
- Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.dll

Further to this, the new dll from the microsoft website appears to have different definitions. For example the Server object does not have a connect method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have is correct. You will get all the DLLs installed if you install AMO. Look under the install directory: Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies. Make sure you reference a major build of 14 or higher in your project.